# RegEx for N number of spaces in a string

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, spaces, regex-greedy

I am looking to create groups, that are separated by 4 spaces
The problem is that if the group contains any space, other than the 4 space separator, there is no match with the regex I have tried so far

This is what I have tried.
Let's say I have these 2 lines, with 4 spaces between the words

```
word 1    word 2
word1    word2
```

and the regex is

```
^([^ {4}]*) {4}([^ {4}]*)$
```

This matches only the 2nd line. The presence of any space anywhere other than the 4 space separator, will not match the line.

My expectation is to match and have the correct groups identified, in both these lines.

Comment: @CertainPerformance `^` makes it opposite it will match anything except `{`, `4` or `}` or `space`

Comment: You have quantifiers (`{4}`) inside character classes (`[]`) which isn't going to make anything work. Seems like `^(.*?) {4}(.*)$` would work.

Answer (score 0):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/S0fdoi/2) might help you to divide your input strings into five groups, where the second and fourth groups are the four-space:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*)(\s{4})([a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*)(\s{4})([a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*)
```

[image]

If you may not have <kbd>space</kbd> in your columns, you could simplify it using [this RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/MxG4XU/4):

```
(\w+)(\s{4})(\w+)(\s{4})(\w+)
```

[image]

Comment: I updated the example https://regex101.com/r/MxG4XU/2 There will always be the same amount of separators (4 spaces) in each line. However, there may not be a string in between 2 consecutive 4 line groups. See line 2, with 8 spaces at the end. In this case this regex does not do it. I also added the beginning ^ and $ end line, but you can see in the 3rd match, it takes multiple lines. I don't understand why

Comment: Why do you sometimes use `\s` and sometimes `[ ]`? Same for `\w` and `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. I can't see any sensible pattern here.

Comment: ([a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*)(\s{4})([a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*)(\s{4})([a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*) is the closest, since it account for empty values in columns. However, characters could be anything, not only a-zA-Z0-9_  Basically what is needed between the 4 space separators is: match any character in any number or empty, except 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation and based on the good suggestions here, I came us with [This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/NY7Vit/1):

```
^(.*?)    (.*?)    (.*?)$
```

[image]

On the surface it does what I need. The last line has more 4 space blocks at the end, but that should not happen. Any pitfall that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a non greedy dot star `.*?` approach, you could specify the characters that you want to match.

If your data contains for example only words, you could match 1+ word chars `\w+` followed by a repeating pattern `(\w+(?: \w+)*)` to match a space and 1+ word chars followed by matching 4 spaces.

Note that if you want to match more that a word character, you could use a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and add the characters that you would allow to match.

```
^(\w+(?: \w+)*) {4}(\w+(?: \w+)*) {4}(\w+(?: \w+)*)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vPJNVf/1)